# A <:< SomeType parameter declaration

Tags: scala, function

Looking at `scala.Option[T]` sources I found the following implicit parameter declaration `implicit ev: Null <:< A1`. Trying it myself

```
class Test[T](val i: Int){
  def test(p: T <:< Option[Int]) = 1
}
```

I found that `p` looks like a `Function1`. It has `apply`, `andThen` etc methods. What would be the difference if we wrote:

```
class TestMatch[T](val i: Int){
    def test(p: T <:< Option[Int]) =  //..
    def test2(p: T => Option[Int]) =  //...
}
```

Is there some principal difference between singatures of `test` and `test2`? This example beahves is this:

```
tm.test2(x => { //fine
  println(x)
  Some(x)
})

tm.test(x => { //Compile error
  println(x)
  Some(x)
})
```

I also tried this:

```
tm.test(x <:< { //Compile error
  println(x)
  Some(x)
})
```

but it didn't work either. How to use `test`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found that `p` looks like a `Function1`

`<:<` is defined as:

```
sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) with Serializable
```

Which is a derived of `Function1[From, To]`, and that's where you're seeing `apply` and `andThen` come from. `<:<` means a generic parameter type constraint,  where `T` is a subtype of `Option[Int]`.

Generally, `<:<` is meant to be used as a *type constraint* which forces an implicit evidence to be in scope:

> An instance of `A <:< B` witnesses that `A` is a subtype of `B`. 
>   Requiring an implicit argument of the type `A <:< B` encodes the generalized constraint `A <: B`.

---

> But couldn't you explain who creates this implicit <:< parameter?
>   Where did it come from? I guess compiler's aware about <:< and know
>   what to do with it

In your example, there is no implicit evidence created. You're simply using `<:<` as a *type*, not a constraint. If you wanted to create one, you'd need to do it yourself by declaring the implicit:

```
def greaterThan[T](x: T, y: T)(implicit ev: T <:< Ordered[T]): Boolean = x > y
```

Comment: But how can I use `test`? Is there a way to call it?

Comment: But `<:<` is a function. It's defined in `Predef` as `sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) with Serializable`

Comment: @Kolmar That still doesn't make `p` a `Function1`. It only means that the constraint is using infix notation, where it is actually defined as `<:<[T, Option[Int]]`

Comment: Why? It's a function of one argument and its `apply` and `andThen` are inherited straight from `Function1`. I mean the `extends (From => To)` part.

Comment: @Kolmar You're right. It's a derive of `From => To` actually making it a `Function1`. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: I wonder if that should be a question in itself, but what is the use of `<:<` over a simple function ?

Comment: @Dici What do you mean by "simple function"?

Comment: @Dici Digging into docs I found that it was intendednt to use only as an implicit parameter. `To constrain any abstract type T that's in scope in a method's argument list (not just the method's own type parameters) simply add an implicit argument of type `T <:< U`

Comment: @Dici Ahh, I see what you mean. I actually have no good answer for that, not sure it's making too much sense to use it like that.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov if `<:<` is almost equivalent to `=>` except the serialization bit, then I wonder what it is adding

Comment: @stella ok I see, it did look to me like an implicit conversion. Then I guess it's only syntactic sugar

Comment: @Dici But couldn't you explain who creates this `implicit <:<` parameter? Where did it come from? I guess compiler's aware about `<:<` and know what to do with it...

Comment: @stella not sure what you mean but at this rate a new question is probably the way to go :p Comments can only be so long

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov so the use of this seems to be adding a generic type constraint on a method and not on the whole generic class. Correct ?

Answer (score 1):

They have different semantics. In `test` you are stating that `T` is a subtype of `Option[Int]`. In `test2` there is no such constraint.

Comment: So how to call `test2`? What should I pass as a parameter in order to make it compile?